# createFromFormat not returning the correct hour

Tags: php, date

My database has date entries like this:
29th August 20:00 PM

```
echo $datetest;
//prints 29th August 20:00 PM

$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('jS F H:i A', $datetest)
$startHoursString = $myDateTime->format('H');

echo $startHoursString;
// prints 08 instead of 20
```

I was expecting that $startHoursString would be 20 instead of 8.

Could anyone shed some light on this or a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried 'hh', 'h', 'HH', etc.?

Comment: First off. Change your date column type to `datetime` and insert to that column in your database (I'm assuming MySQL) with `now()`

Comment: yes if i try
$startHoursString = $myDateTime->format('HH');
It prints 0808 instead of 20.

Comment: I can't change the format of the original date(29th August 20:00 PM). It is part of a complex system that I cannot change.

Comment: Like @ThisBoyPerforms suggested you should always make use of the proper `DATATYPE` when possible on MYSQL columns so you don't suffer from using a database. It's meant to simplify your life not to complicate it, that's why there are different `DATATYPE` available.

Comment: @Prix - I've checked the timezone issue and it doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is dirty hack, but it should work, if you are sure that dates are in this `AM/PM` format, you'll have to remove last 3 characters from the string (AM or PM plus space):

`$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('jS F H:i', substr($datetest, 0, -3));`

Fiddle [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dUwyxG).

Also, remember that using `AM/PM` is valid for up to 12 Hour, 20:00 AM/PM is *INVALID* format.

Comment: That's a perfect answer. Seems to work, so the idea is to chop out the AM/PM and then convert it. Many thanks!

Comment: Also check the `createFromFormat()` function, we now DO NOT NEED the `A` modifier, **only** `jS F H:i`

Comment: Many thanks, i spot it now. I had tried every avenue and your hack will do fine.